# Error when executing Python code "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sessionid' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to execute python suite I run into following error.

```
File "botclient.py", line 59, in <module>
botcode.utils.addUser(loginUri, logoutUri1, logoutUri2, addUserUri, dbUri, dataMap)
File "/root/botclient/clcode/utils.py", line 877, in addUser
logout(logoutUri1, sessionid, dataMap)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sessionid' referenced before assignment
```

I do not see this error when I execute the function separately. 
Here is the addUser function I'm using

```
def addUser(loginUri, logoutUri1, logoutUri2, addUserUri, dbUri, dataMap):
        try:
            response = login(loginUri, dataMap)
            sessionid = response.split("var jsessionid = '")[1].split("'")[0]
            csrftoken = response.split("wap.csrf_token=\"")[1].split("\"")[0]
            configManager = getDBData("select+instanceid+from+XGS_GROUP+where+instancename%3D%27Config+Managers%27", sessionid, csrftoken, dbUri, dataMap)
            nbiWrite = getDBData("select+instanceid+from+XGS_GROUP+where+instancename%3D%27NBI+Write%27", sessionid, csrftoken, dbUri, dataMap)
            rootDomain = getDBData("select+instanceid+from+XGS_GROUP+where+instancename%3D%27ROOT-DOMAIN%27", sessionid, csrftoken, dbUri, dataMap)
            addUserData = '''------WebKitFormBoundarySkroBjW9bHRdh2YW\r\nContent-Disposition''' 
            addUserPost(addUserUri, addUserData, sessionid, csrftoken, dataMap)

        except Exception as err:
             log(str(traceback.format_exc()))
             dataMap["failureReason"] = "Issue in user addition"
        finally:
             logout(logoutUri1, sessionid, dataMap)
```

What is that I'm missing with `sessionid`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Linux or `vi`, I removed those tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how sessionid is only defined when the "try" statement is executed to completion.

When there is an exception, sessionid remains undefined, and in your "finally" statement, it will break.

Answer (score 1):

If there's an exception raised on the first line in your `try` block, sessionid will have not been assigned. So when you try to access it in your `finally` block, it throws an error because sessionid basically doesn't exist for you at that point.

One way to fix this would be to put sessionid outside/before the try/except block. That way, you know it's been declared.